# Using a .htaccess to RewriteRule and Redirect 301 at the same time?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a couple of specific URLs that I want to display differently on my website. For example I want "/contact.php" to become "/contact". So I added this to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
```

And to avoid having 2 different URLS pointing to the same page, I also want to do a 301 redirect between the old URL and the new one:

```
Redirect 301 /contact.php http://www.example.com/contact
```

Each of the line above works well separately. But if I add them both in my htaccess, I have a redirect loop. How can I fix that?

In the end, if I either type "/contact" or "/contact.php", I want to see the contact page with the url "/contact".

---

Edit: I also tried things like that, and it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^/contact\.php$ http://www.example.com/contact [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/contact$ /contact.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it will indeed cause redirection loop since `mod_rewrite` rules are applied in a loop.** Here value of `REQUEST_URI` changes to `contact.php` after first rule and to `contact` by your second rule.

To avoid this looping you need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` in your external redirect rule as `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some other rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`.

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from /contact.php to /contact  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(contact)\.php\[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from /contact to /contact.php
RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Change `302` to `301` once you make sure it is working fine for you.